# How do I use AG Grid (Server-Side Row Model) and Apollo GraphQL client, with Relay-style cursor pagination in React?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, pagination, ag-grid, apollo

In my React application, I am using the Apollo Client, with [relayStylePagination()](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/#relay-style-cursor-pagination). Our API uses the [Connection pattern](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm) to provide the data.

[image: Apollo Client]

I want to introduce AG Grid to display large sets of data and to be able to use both pagination and infinite scroll behaviour. This implies the use of a [Server-Side row model](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-model/#server-side-row-model) in my implementation.

This has proven to be difficult. I can't find any examples of this particular setup in the wild. AG Grid's [own examples](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-operations-graphql/#server-side-datasource) using GraphQL, utilise start and end rows to build and perform the paginated requests.

I need to use cursor-based pagination to build my queries. As seen on line 105 in my test-code below, I want to update the variable `after` (currently set to `null` in order to fetch the 10 first results).

[image: Test implementation]

Any and all input, nudges in the right direction and/or examples on how to do this is highly appreciated.